# Launching process from shell is fine, doesn't work with ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala

I am playing around with Scala's ProcessBuilder and I am trying to launch the `bitcoin-cli` from Scala.

This works fine from the shell and the command to execute it is simply `bitcoin-cli`

However if I try and launch it from the scala REPL I get an error:

```
chris@chris:~$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "bitcoin-cli".!!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:101)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)


scala>
```

Why does this error out?

EDIT:

```
scala> Process("bitcoin-cli").!!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:101)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: What reason does your program `bitcoin-cli` return a 1 on exit?

Comment: Do an `echo $?` after running it from the shell to see if it also has an exit value of 1 there.

Comment: It does return a 1 in that case. I'm looking through documentation for it right now and I am not finding the answer @JohnAment

Comment: From the little bit of searching I did, it looks like `bitcoin-cli` is used for communicating with `bitcoind`. My guess is that `bitcoin-cli` exits with 1 when called without options because without options it has nothing to communicate with `bitcoind`. What happens when you invoke `bitcoin-cli` with options?